# Connecting to an active directory on an external network without the password

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices

A scenario where I need to query an active directory on an external network but I don't have the password of a user on the network. I've been trying a variety of methods from DirectServices and DirectoryServices.AccoutnMAnagement but end up eith the same exception "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." Any suggestions or remarks on if this is possible at all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Errr - wouldn't this be a massive security hole if it was permitted (anonymous querying of a remote resource)? Or am I misunderstanding what you are saying?!

Comment: Depends on what you are querying, can you please provide more details of exactly what you are querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible.  You would need the company that owns the directory to provide an account for you to use, typically a service account that has no other use.